# How to generate 60,000 random numbers insert in an AVL tree and do reshuffle operation?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

My goal is to **generate 600,000 numbers and insert them into an AVL tree. Then I should reshuffle it after that delete a number from AVL tree.**

Now I am facing two problems.

***1. I would like to use for loop in my main method to insert numbers.
    However, it always generates and prints one number.*

          *2. How can I reshuffle those numbers? I think it is feasible that print all of the numbers and put them into a list, then
    reshuffle it, which is a bit of complex.***

This is my code (Based on GeeksforGeeks)

***Method part:***

```
static class Node { 
    int key, height; 
    Node left, right; 

    Node(int d) { 
        key = d; 
        height = 1; 
    } 
} 

static class AVLTree { 

    Node root; 

    // A utility function to get the height of the tree 
    int height(Node N) { 
        if (N == null) 
            return 0; 

        return N.height; 
    } 

    // A utility function to get maximum of two integers 
    int max(int a, int b) { 
        return (a > b) ? a : b; 
    } 

    // A utility function to right rotate subtree rooted with y 
    // See the diagram given above. 
    Node rightRotate(Node y) { 
        Node x = y.left; 
        Node T2 = x.right; 

        // Perform rotation 
        x.right = y; 
        y.left = T2; 

        // Update heights 
        y.height = max(height(y.left), height(y.right)) + 1; 
        x.height = max(height(x.left), height(x.right)) + 1; 

        // Return new root 
        return x; 
    } 

    // A utility function to left rotate subtree rooted with x 
    // See the diagram given above. 
    Node leftRotate(Node x) { 
        Node y = x.right; 
        Node T2 = y.left; 

        // Perform rotation 
        y.left = x; 
        x.right = T2; 

        // Update heights 
        x.height = max(height(x.left), height(x.right)) + 1; 
        y.height = max(height(y.left), height(y.right)) + 1; 

        // Return new root 
        return y; 
    } 

    // Get Balance factor of node N 
    int getBalance(Node N) { 
        if (N == null) 
            return 0; 

        return height(N.left) - height(N.right); 
    } 

    Node insert(Node node, int key) { 

        /* 1. Perform the normal BST insertion */
        if (node == null) 
            return (new Node(key)); 

        if (key < node.key) 
            node.left = insert(node.left, key); 
        else if (key > node.key) 
            node.right = insert(node.right, key); 
        else // Duplicate keys not allowed 
            return node; 

        /* 2. Update height of this ancestor node */
        node.height = 1 + max(height(node.left), 
                            height(node.right)); 

        /* 3. Get the balance factor of this ancestor 
            node to check whether this node became 
            unbalanced */
        int balance = getBalance(node); 

        // If this node becomes unbalanced, then there 
        // are 4 cases Left Left Case 
        if (balance > 1 && key < node.left.key) 
            return rightRotate(node); 

        // Right Right Case 
        if (balance < -1 && key > node.right.key) 
            return leftRotate(node); 

        // Left Right Case 
        if (balance > 1 && key > node.left.key) { 
            node.left = leftRotate(node.left); 
            return rightRotate(node); 
        } 

        // Right Left Case 
        if (balance < -1 && key < node.right.key) { 
            node.right = rightRotate(node.right); 
            return leftRotate(node); 
        } 

        /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
        return node; 
    }

    Node minValueNode(Node node)  
    {  
        Node current = node;  

        /* loop down to find the leftmost leaf */
        while (current.left != null)  
        current = current.left;  

        return current;  
    }  

    Node deleteNode(Node root, int key)  
    {  
        // STEP 1: PERFORM STANDARD BST DELETE  
        if (root == null)  
            return root;  

        // If the key to be deleted is smaller than  
        // the root's key, then it lies in left subtree  
        if (key < root.key)  
            root.left = deleteNode(root.left, key);  

        // If the key to be deleted is greater than the  
        // root's key, then it lies in right subtree  
        else if (key > root.key)  
            root.right = deleteNode(root.right, key);  

        // if key is same as root's key, then this is the node  
        // to be deleted  
        else
        {  

            // node with only one child or no child  
            if ((root.left == null) || (root.right == null))  
            {  
                Node temp = null;  
                if (temp == root.left)  
                    temp = root.right;  
                else
                    temp = root.left;  

                // No child case  
                if (temp == null)  
                {  
                    temp = root;  
                    root = null;  
                }  
                else // One child case  
                    root = temp; // Copy the contents of  
                                // the non-empty child  
            }  
            else
            {  

                // node with two children: Get the inorder  
                // successor (smallest in the right subtree)  
                Node temp = minValueNode(root.right);  

                // Copy the inorder successor's data to this node  
                root.key = temp.key;  

                // Delete the inorder successor  
                root.right = deleteNode(root.right, temp.key);  
            }  
        }  

        // If the tree had only one node then return  
        if (root == null)  
            return root;  

        // STEP 2: UPDATE HEIGHT OF THE CURRENT NODE  
        root.height = max(height(root.left), height(root.right)) + 1;  

        // STEP 3: GET THE BALANCE FACTOR OF THIS NODE (to check whether  
        // this node became unbalanced)  
        int balance = getBalance(root);  

        // If this node becomes unbalanced, then there are 4 cases  
        // Left Left Case  
        if (balance > 1 && getBalance(root.left) >= 0)  
            return rightRotate(root);  

        // Left Right Case  
        if (balance > 1 && getBalance(root.left) < 0)  
        {  
            root.left = leftRotate(root.left);  
            return rightRotate(root);  
        }  

        // Right Right Case  
        if (balance < -1 && getBalance(root.right) <= 0)  
            return leftRotate(root);  

        // Right Left Case  
        if (balance < -1 && getBalance(root.right) > 0)  
        {  
            root.right = rightRotate(root.right);  
            return leftRotate(root);  
        }  

        return root;  
    }  


    // A utility function to print preorder traversal 
    // of the tree. 
    // The function also prints height of every node 
    void preOrder(Node node) { 
        if (node != null) { 
            System.out.print(node.key + " "); 
            preOrder(node.left); 
            preOrder(node.right); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

***Main method***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AVLTree tree = new AVLTree(); 
    int rand = (int) (Math.random()*600000)+1; 

    /* Constructing tree given in the above figure */
    for (int i=0;i<600000;i++) {
        tree.root=tree.insert(tree.root,rand);
    }


    System.out.println("Preorder traversal" + 
                    " of constructed tree is : "); 
    tree.preOrder(tree.root); 

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're inserting the same number into all your tree nodes. To make each of them different, you need to move the assignment of rand into for loop.

Comment: You mean I also need to generate rand for 60,000 times?

Comment: How else do you think you'll be able to get 600_000 different numbers. Don't worry, the computer should do most of the work. :)

Comment: #2: Why would you *print* the numbers? Just generate the numbers and put them directly into a list, shuffle the list, *then* copy them from list into your AVL tree. --- Of course, the real question is why you would shuffle a list of random numbers. They are already random. Shuffling the list will not make the numbers more random than they already are.

Answer (score 2):

Nomadmaker is right, you're generating the random number at declaration time and using same in the for loop every time, you should try this

```
Random random = new Random();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 60000 ; ++i)
tree.root = tree.insert(tree.root,random.nextInt(60000));
```